# Bilinear filtering of output image in Direct3D 11

Tags: directx11, filtering

I'd like to render something at one resolution, but display it in a window at another resolution (e.g. render the scene at 640x480 and stretch it to a 1024x768 window).

Simply resizing the window after creation allows this to work - however, the image is filtered using nearest-neighbor. Is there a way to change the filtering algorithm to e.g. bilinear?